# utilReplaceInResponse not showing changes in the browser

Tags: fiddler

Working in FiddlerScript, I've got some changes being made in the OnBeforeResponse method that used to work on a different machine (now long gone) but aren't working for me now.  I've boiled it down to the following basic example.

On the fiddler sandbox page, I'm trying to replace the word *per item* with the words *per item*    URL:  http://webdbg.com/sandbox/shop/

Fiddler script file modified from the original to have two new lines.  1 to decode the session and 1 to replace in the response as per all examples I've seen and what used to work for me.

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();  //Added this.
    oSession.utilReplaceInResponse("per item", "per item");  //Added this

    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
}
```

After saving the above fiddlerscript file and refreshing the page, I'm not seeing the replaces show in the browser.   If I look in the Fiddler inspector, I **am** seeing the replaces.   This means that the OnBeforeResponse is indeed being called at some point and the `utilReplaceInResponse` is also executing.

Additional oddity, if I put breakpoints after all responses (Fiddler -> Rules -> Automatic Breakpoints -> After Responses) and refresh the page, the response hits the breakpoint as expected and I click *Run to Completion* and the browser **does show** the replacement.  So:  No breakpoint, page doesn't show replacements in the rendered page.  With breakpoint and simply running to completion, the page does show the replacements.

Why isn't the page showing the changes in the browser even though it shows them in the Fiddler inspector, or if I have a breakpoint set?

.

**SOLUTION**  Had the *Stream* option selected in the main toolbar - deselected that and it works as expected.

.

Environment:  Fiddler v2.4.5.3 - 64-bit AMD64, VM: 114.00mb, WS: 132.00mb .NET 2.0.50727.5472 WinNT 6.1.7601 SP1

Seen on both IE9 and Chrome31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved myself.

I had the Stream option enabled in the toolbar. (Doh!)  De-select that and the replacement in the OnBeforeResponse works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a new Fiddler version feature, but I had to add the following line to get my find/replace to work:

```
oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
```